# laravel redirect to shows a message in white screen

Tags: redirect, laravel

In my project only one section that is the date booking taking section , when the appointment is booked the redirect message

`"redirecting to <url>" shows in a white screen`.

This happens only in this function. I have already checked the layout used in this page for any space before the `Doctype` but it was fine, and also checked any space before `<?php and ?> in the head.blade.php` . But nothing noticed.

This started showing suddenly from yesterday where i just wrote a php code in head for checking and displaying `meta title and meta description`. 
The redirect code used in the end of controller function is:

```
return Redirect::to('/home/my-profile/'.$d_id.'#menu5');
```

Can anyone please tell me how to avoid this message from displaying like this.?

Comment: post the controller. and routes.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, the problem for me was I had a space in the controller before the  `<?php` tag

Comment: Hi sven .. can u please tell me where the space occurs in your controller method??

Comment: in the beginning of the file i had [space]<?php so there was one space before the php openings tags, after removeing this space it didnt show the white page anymore.

Comment: but sven i had checked my all controllers and my routes now. there is no space before php starting tags and i'm not using the end tags so that no space after that will cause the problem.. i'm so tired of this issue.. couldn't find the reason for this issue.. :(

Comment: oh..at last i've found the reason.. it was the space in the model file.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. Instead of spaces, there were hidden Byte Order Mark (BOM) characters at the beginning of the PHP file causing the redirect message. To remove the BOM characters, save the code in an ANSI .txt file, create a new PHP file and paste the code from the ANSI file to the new PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced same issue once, 
I fixed it by removing whitespaces before `<?php` in one of my routes file.
Check your all routes and controller file if there is any whitespaces before opening PHP tag.